# android opencv face detection in video file

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

Using the opencv face detect sample I was able to detect faces in a live stream and detect face in an image by converting bitmap to mat and use the same approach as opencv face detect sample. I would like to ask, How can I do it in a video file like avi or mp4. I already loaded a video in a videoview but I don't know how to make the video file as an input so I can detect faces. Guidance, tutorial links, steps, samples is needed. Any will do. Thank you so much. Don't know how to read c++.

Comment: any luck? I am now facing the same issue...